# GitLab API get commit count of a branch

Tags: gitlab

Is there a GitLab API to get the commit count of a specific branch?

I can get the commits of the branch using following curl command, but not the commit count.

```
curl -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my_private_token>" "http://<my_locally_hosted_web_server>/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits/?ref_name=master"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the number of pages (see also gitlab [pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#pagination)) and iterate over pages counting json array elements using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) :

```
TOTAL_PAGES=$(curl -Ss -k --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my_private_token>" "http://<my_locally_hosted_web_server>/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits/?ref_name=master" | grep x-total-pages | cut -d':' -f2 )

for ((i=1;i<=TOTAL_PAGES;i++)); do 
  SUM=$(($SUM + $(curl -Ss -k --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my_private_token>" "http://<my_locally_hosted_web_server>/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits/?ref_name=master&per_page=100&page=$i" | jq -r '. | length'))); 
done; 

echo $SUM
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the headers informations 'X-Total' :

```
commits_count=$(curl -Ss -k --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my_private_token>" "http://<my_locally_hosted_web_server>/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/commits?per_page=5" | grep -m 1 X-Total | cut -d':' -f2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP-CURL example using iteration through contributors

```html
    function commitStatistics()
    {
        $projectId = 100;
        $projectPrivateToken = "secretToken123";
        $url = $this->projectUrl . "/api/v4/projects/$projectId/repository/contributors";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('PRIVATE-TOKEN:' . $projectPrivateToken));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $total_counter = 0;
        foreach (json_decode($result) as $contributor) {
            $total_counter += $contributor->commits;
        }

        return $total_counter;
    }
```